# php use array as index to array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array `$dictionary` and an array `$words` how can I use an array (`$words`) to index another array (`$dictionary`)?

The easiest I can think is:

```
function dict_dispatch($word,$dictionary) {
    return $dictionary[$word];
}

$translated = array_map('dict_dispatch', $words, 
                          array_fill(0, count($words), $dictionary));
```

e.g.

For example:

```
$dictionary = array("john_the_king"=>"John-The-King", "nick_great"=>"Nick-Great-2001");
$words=array("john_the_king","nick_great");

$translated = <??>

assert($translated==array("John-The-King","Nick-Great-2001"));
```

Notice that $dictionary might be quite large and it would be very nice if this operation is as fast as possible (that's why I don't use foreach in first place)

Comment: Are you saying you want to construct an array from another array, using an array of indexes?

Comment: Could you give a small example of what data you would have and what you'd like to end up with?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I Just added an example

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: It's correct - but I'm wondering if there's something a bit more native/faster as in Ruby/Python...

Comment: There's no performance benefit to using `array_map` over `foreach` and some have reported as actually being slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my original solution is more or less the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how efficient this is, but it works.

```
$translated = array_values(array_intersect_key($dictionary, array_flip($words)));
```

Comment: It's very good but a bit tricky because array_flip is naughty and will not work very well if we have e.g. $words=array("john_the_king","nick_great","john_the_king"); It seems quite efficient as far as I can tell.

Comment: Actually, a quick test using `microtime()` shows it to be a bit slower than the OP's code.

Comment: @neverlastn: I didn't think of that, yeah that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [something like this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) where you use array of the keys and another for the values?

```
$translated = array_combine($words, $dictionary);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not exactly. I added an example for clarity.